# Why is the CM-type preserved after base changing from char 0 to char p?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, complex-multiplication

There is a transition in the theory of complex multiplication which seems to be glossed over in all expositions I can find. I would like to explicitly find a theorem that allows me to do this.

**Background**:

Let us review the construction of a complex abelian variety $A$ with complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ given by Taniyama-Shimura. We begin with $\mathbb{C}^g/\Phi(\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N])$ equipped with a Riemann form, where the embedding is given by:

$$\Phi: \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N] \to \mathbb{C}^g$$ $$a \mapsto (\sigma_1(a),..., \sigma_g(a))$$

where $\sigma_1, ..., \sigma_g$ are nonconjugate embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N) \to \mathbb{C}$.

There is an action of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N] =: L$, a commutative subgroup of $End_{\mathbb{Q}}(A)$ on the holomorphic tangent space of $A$. This action is defined by taking
$$\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_N] \to End_{\mathbb{Q}}(A)$$

$$\alpha \times (z_1, ..., z_g) \mapsto (\sigma_1(\alpha)z_1, ..., \sigma_g(\alpha)z_g)$$

This action, the $CM$-type of $A$ gives a spectral decomposition of $\text{Lie } A$ (the holomorphic tangent space at the identity).

---

In many expositions, applying the Taniyama-Shimura formula to derive the height of the formal group law of an abelian variety has the following pattern.

We begin with an abelian variety $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ with complex multiplication by $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$. Then, we end up because of "good reduction over $p$" with an abelian variety $B$ over a different field (it is not clear to me if this field is the reflex field or a field of characteristic $p$) with complex multiplication by a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Magically, the $CM$-type of $B$ is the same as that of $A$.

> **Q0.** What is a reference which states that the $CM$-type of $A$ and $B$ are the same?
>
> **Q1.**  Why is the $CM$-type of $A$ is the same as that of $B$?

In the char $p$ setting, it seems that CM-type is now a description of the action of the maximal commutative subgroup of $End_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(B)$.

> **Q2.** Is there a way to write $B$ as a similar lattice? Along the lines of $W(F_q)^g/(\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_N])$ or $F_q^\text{ g}/(\mathbb{Z}_p[\zeta_N])$ ?

Comment: Do you have a reference that states that there is complex multiplication by $\mathbb Q_p$? Do you have a reference that states this? If not, why do you think this?

Comment: In general it would be good to provide a reference where this notation $B$ is used, because as you mention you are not sure what $B$ means.